# how to make coins explode out of monster in phaser?

Tags: phaser

I am trying to make coins explode out of a monster when it is killed.
the explode would be similar to this example: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/particles/diamond-burst

I also want the coins to be clicked individually similar to this example:
http://phaser.io/examples/v2/groups/call-all-input

I am confused as to how to incorporate the two above examples together. Is emitting particles the way to go? I am also confused as to how to set each coin to have a different value depending on the monster.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom class for your particle-system instead of the standard-particle.

Use the [`emitter.particleClass`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Particles.Arcade.Emitter.html#particleClass) property (here's an [example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/particles/particle-class) of how to use it).

In that custom class you can then write code that handles the user-interaction etc.